# How to add object in array Angularjs and show this?

Tags: arrays, angularjs, javascript-objects

How to add object in array and show it on web-page?

http://plnkr.co/edit/19w1Q3XhoWQcpxm5SuxX?p=preview

```
$scope.add = function() {
$scope.items.push($scope.item);
$scope.item = '';
```

};

[When I try to add item it's not show on page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWLVr.png)

Comment: Just change the first line of you dd function to  `$scope.items.push({'item':$scope.item});` so the item object will have the same structure of data than the others.

Answer (score 3):

Just change your push code to:

```
$scope.items.push({item: $scope.item});
```

You are trying to push single string to an Array of objects.

you can also change your model in controller to

```
$scope.item = {text: ""}
```

and on your view change ng-model to

```
ng-model="item.text"
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi just edit your function

because its an object , u have to create object and need to push inside an array

```
$scope.add = function() {
    var obj ={};
    obj.item = $scope.item;
    $scope.items.push(obj);
    $scope.item = '';
  };
```